# Como remover cabeçalho SOAP 'Security'

Tags: c#, web-service, soap, wcf

Estou tentando consumir um web service SOAP 1.2 usando um cliente WCF. O problema é, sempre que eu faço uma solicitação uma exceção `MessageSecurityException` ocorre com a seguinte mensagem interna:

```
SOAP header Security was not understood
```

Pelo que eu entendi, o WS não entende o cabeçalho de "Security", que está atualmente marcado como MustUnderstand = "true" no envelope SOAP.

Como posso alterar MustUnderstand para falso / remover o cabeçalho "Security"?

Abaixo está o binding que estou usando agora:

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="CteRecepcaoSoap12">
    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
    <security authenticationMode="CertificateOverTransport"/>
    <httpsTransport requireClientCertificate="true"/>
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

Comment: Você criou uma Web Reference ou uma Service Reference?

Comment: @jbueno Criei uma Service Reference.

Comment: Ok. E qual a extensão do serviço?

Comment: @jbueno O WS usa ASMX, se é isso o que você quis dizer.

Comment: Retirar o cabeçalho de segurança _nunca_ é uma boa ideia porque vai permitir ataques de MItM. Dito isso, existem formas de validar se o cabeçalho é válido (que não tenho fácil, desculpe :( ).

Comment: @EricWu concordo, suponho que tirar este cabeçalho seja uma má ideia, mas eu não controlo esse WS. Só posso consumir. Obrigado pelo input :)